# Webinar with WebRTC

Tags: html, webrtc

I'd like to host a webinar right on my website. If I cap the webinar to 5 people, essentially a 6 person video chat, can I do it all with HTML5 and WebRTC?

Or is the web tech not there yet?

Comment: The only limitation is your bandwidth and CPU power. It's not unheard of to have a 6 person video chat via WebRTC, but you'll have to try specifically for your case to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you have to use a mediaserver like Kurento. It stands for broadcasting your media stream to the listeners

Comment: Why do you "have to" use a media server?

Comment: I always keep in mind, that any solution should be scalable. Our tests show that many clients unable to stream to 6 peers simultaneously due CPU and Uplink limitations.

Comment: Sure, but the question is explicitly about capping it to 6 peers. Do you have hard data that 6 peers is too much to handle in a P2P fashion and that it *requires* a streaming server?

Comment: Thanks, gents. These are the types of questions I'm thinking through. Most likely we'll cap our webinars to a small private group, maybe even four participants and myself.